# Find the boundaries of a local maxima

Tags: matlab

I have a 2D image (matrix). I have found the local maxima of this image. Now I want to define the boundaries around each local maxima in such a way that I want all the pixels around the local maxima that have a value above 85% of the maximum.

Here is my existing code:

```
function [location]= Mfind_peak_2D( Image,varargin ) 
    p = inputParser; 
    addParamValue(p,'max_n_loc_max',5); 
    addParamValue(p,'nb_size',3); 
    addParamValue(p,'thre',0); 
    addParamValue(p,'drop',0.15); 
    parse(p,varargin{:}); 
    p=p.Results; 
    if sum(isnan(Image(:)))>0 
        Image(isnan(Image))=0;
    end 
    hLocalMax = vision.LocalMaximaFinder; 
    hLocalMax.MaximumNumLocalMaxima = p.max_n_loc_max;
    hLocalMax.NeighborhoodSize = [p.nb_size p.nb_size];
end
```

Comment: how did you find the local maxima?

Comment: This is the function I wrote to find the local maxima. Once I find those maxima I have to draw a boundary around them and take only those pixels which are at least 85% of the peak. And then  some peaks are very close to each other so I have to merge them and make only one peak (if they have some shared pixels within their boundaries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job (the code is full of comments and should be pretty self-explanatory but if you have doubts feel free to ask for more details):

```
% Load the image...

img = imread('peppers.png');
img = rgb2gray(img);

% Find the local maxima...

mask = ones(3);
mask(5) = 0;

img_dil = imdilate(img,mask);
lm = img > img_dil;

% Find the neighboring pixels of the local maxima...

img_size = size(img);
img_h = img_size(1);
img_w = img_size(2);

res = cell(sum(sum(lm)),3);
res_off = 1;

for i = 1:img_h
    for j = 1:img_w

        if (~lm(i,j))
            continue;
        end

        value = img(i,j);
        value_thr = value * 0.85;

        % Retrieve the neighboring column and row offsets...
        c = bsxfun(@plus,j,[-1  0  1 -1  1 -1  0  1]);
        r = bsxfun(@plus,i,[-1 -1 -1  0  0  1  1  1]);

        % Filter the invalid positions...
        idx = (c > 0) & (c <= img_w) & (r > 0) & (r <= img_h);

        % Transform the valid positions into linear indices...
        idx = (((idx .* c) - 1) .* img_h) + (idx .* r);
        idx = reshape(idx.',1,numel(idx));
        idx = idx(idx > 0);

        % Retrieve the neighbors and filter them based on te threshold...
        neighbors = img(idx);
        neighbors = neighbors(neighbors > value_thr);

        % Update the final result...
        res(res_off,:) = {sub2ind(img_size,i,j) value neighbors};
        res_off = res_off + 1;
    end
end

res = sortrows(res,1);
```

The variable `res` will be a cell matrix with `three` columns: the first one contain the linear indices to the local maxima of the image, the second one contains the values of the local maxima and the third one a vector with the pixels around the local maxima that fall within the specified threshold.

Comment: Thanks. I have a few questions. First it finds the local maximum. So what if I have the indices  of the local maxim with the function that I have added above? Second there are two variables w and h which are not defined. And last one, I thought for each local maxim I make a binary matrix like SS= IMAGE>=0.85 *V. Here V is the value of one local maxima, and IMAGE is the image matrix. Then SS would be a binary matrix composed of 0 and 1. There would islands of ones. Then I have to find that Island which has the local maxima. Is it doable?

Comment: Give me the time to sum up all this inside code (w and h are width and height of the image, I slightly changed the code above and there should be no errors).

Comment: On a side note, how do you calculate local maxima?

Comment: The code is not reproductible and the code seems to be truncated.

Comment: Please tell me what error you are getting. The Image is a 2D matrix.

Comment: I'm wondering if you tried to run the fuction you pasted. It doesn't even compile. All it does is initializing a LocalMaximaFinder. Then? Where is the computation?